# Queryset no django sem case-sensitive

Tags: python, django, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou com uma dúvida quanto a Querysets no Django.

Preciso fazer uma busca num campo que é um Charfield, só que a pesquisa que estou fazendo aparenta ser case sensitive. E eu queria que ao procurar por 'Stack' a pesquisa retornasse um campo que é 'stack overflow'. Eis o model da classe cuja pesquisa será realizada.

```
class Node(models.Model):

objects = GChartsManager()

idnode = models.IntegerField(db_column='idSITE', primary_key=True, editable=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
nome = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
informacoes = models.CharField(db_column='INFORMATION', max_length=45, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'site'
```

E o código que uso para realizar a pesquisa

```
Node.objects.filter(nome__contains = keyword)
```

Sendo keyword a variável que contém o valor a ser pesquisado.

E também gostaria de saber como faço para criar uma queryset vazia e "adicionar itens" nela. Por exemplo eu quero fazer uma queryset com esses 2 resultados, quero que ambos fiquem na mesma query set.

```
Node.objects.filter(nome__contains = 'Stack')

Node.objects.filter(nome__contains = 'internet')
```

Answer (score 2):

Vários filtros do Django possuem uma variante que leva em consideração maiúsculas/minúsculas e outra variante que não leva. No caso do `contains` é a [`icontains`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1950/215):

```
Node.objects.filter(nome__icontains = keyword)
```

Há também a `exact` e `iexact`, `startswith` e `istartswith`, etc.

Quanto à sua outra dúvida, você pode chamar `filter` sem nenhum parâmetro (ou talvez `all`, não tenho certeza) e depois chamar métodos adicionais na `QuerySet`. Cada chamada de método restringe ainda mais o que a *query* faz (o SQL só será executado de fato quando você tentar ler o resultado da `QuerySet`, até lá você pode modificá-la à vontade). Um exemplo seria:

```
qs = Node.objects.filter()                   # select * from app_node;

qs = qs.filter(nome__contains = 'Stack')     # select * from app_node
                                             # where nome like 'Stack';

qs = qs.filter(nome__contains = 'internet')  # select * from app_node
                                             # where nome like 'Stack'
                                             # and nome like 'internet';

qs = qs[10:30] # select * from app_node
               # where nome like 'Stack' and nome like 'internet'
               # limit 20 offset 10;

x = qs[0] # Aqui o SQL será executado, e você não pode mais mexer na QuerySet
```

Uma opção mais flexível (que inclusive permite combinar condições com OU em vez de só AND) é usando [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q):

```
from django.db.models import Q

tem_stack = Q(nome__contains = 'Stack')
tem_internet = Q(nome__contains = 'internet')

e = Node.objects.filter(tem_stack & tem_internet)
ou = Node.objects.filter(tem_stack | tem_internet)
```

Comment: Muito bem detalhado, eu uso outro framework, mas vou dar uma olhada neste agora devido esta parte dos Models +1