# Pesquisa com OR no Django

Tags: banco-de-dados, python, django

Olá estou desenvolvendo minha 1° aplicação no Django e estou tendo dificuldade com pesquisas mais complexas no DB.

Aqui está meu MODEL:

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    objects = GChartsManager()

    idtag = models.IntegerField(db_column='idTAG', primary_key=True, editable=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    desvio = models.FloatField(db_column='DEVIATION', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tempo_max = models.IntegerField(db_column='TIME_MAX', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    conv_rate = models.IntegerField(db_column='CONV_RATE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    taginfo_idtaginfo1 = models.ForeignKey('Taginfo', db_column='tagInfo_idTAGINFO')  # Field name made lowercase.
    datasource_idestacao_meteo = models.ForeignKey(Datasource, db_column='datasource_idDATASOURCE', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'id = %s / id tagInfo => %s' % (self.idtag, self.taginfo_idtaginfo1)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tag'


class Taginfo(models.Model):

    objects = GChartsManager()

    idtaginfo = models.IntegerField(db_column='idTAGINFO', primary_key=True, editable=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nome = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=45)  # Field name made lowercase.
    descricao = models.CharField(db_column='DESCRIPTION', max_length=255, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'name = %s / description = %s' % (self.nome, self.descricao)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'taginfo'
```

E eu quero fazer uma pesquisa achando todas as Tag´s de um vários Taginfo´s, ou seja a variável tags é na verdade vários objetos, sempre:

```
tagInfos = Taginfo.objects.filter()
        for tag in tags:
            tagInfos = tagInfos.filter(idtaginfo = tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1.idtaginfo)
```

Porém essa pesquisa não me retorna nada.
Eu já fiz essa pergunta e me responderam que assim funcionaria ou usando objetos Q, [Objetos Q](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66532/queryset-no-django-sem-case-sensitive/66554#66554) porém não entendi como faria isso no meu caso onde a quantidade de itens é variável, de 0 à n.
Agradeço desde já a ajuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer pegar todas as Tags de um TagInfo é uma busca simples, já que você tem um `ForeignKey` em `Tag`

`tags = Tag.objects.filter(taginfo_idtaginfo1__in=[LIST_OF_IDS])`

Comment: Desculpe, eu expliquei errado o código, já consertei, é uma busca de várias Taginfo de várias Tags, e eu gostaria de colocar todas essas num único queryset para ser passado para o template.

Comment: `tags = Tag.objects.filter(taginfo_idtaginfo1__in=[LIST_OF_IDS])`

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado @Jair Henrique.